# How to display Maximum Discount Product in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have `products` table in my database, and there are two columns with `totalprice` and `saleprice`, when I am adding a product from backend I submit both prices. I want to calculate the maximum offer on the product (for calculate the offer logic will be something like this, `offer=totalprice/saleprice`), and I want to display those products on my website homegae, but I don't know how I can do it in Django. Please let me guide how I can add the logic in `views.py` file.

here is my views.py file...

```
def home(request):
   product= Product.objects.filter(featured=True).order_by('-created_at')[0:8]
   subc=Product.objects.filter(discount=30).order_by('-created_at')
   return render(request, 'mainpage/index.html',
              {'product':product,'subc':subc})
```

here is my models.py file

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
   slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
   subcategory=models.ForeignKey('SubCategory', related_name='prosubcat', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
   totalprice=models.IntegerField()
   saleprice = models.IntegerField()
   title=models.CharField(max_length=225)
   description = models.TextField()
   overview = models.TextField(null=True)
   featured = models.BooleanField(null=True)
   trending=models.BooleanField(null=True)
   image= models.ImageField(blank=True)
   tags = TaggableManager()
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses)  in your queryset like this.

```
from django.db.models import F
def home(request):
       products= Product.objects.filter(featured=True).annotate(offer=F('totalprice')-F('saleprice'))
```

Now in the template you can do like this:

```
{% for product in products %}
      Product Offer:{{ product.offer }}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:** To calculate the percentage try this.

```
Product.objects.filter(featured=True).annotate(offer=((F('totalprice')-F('saleprice'))/F('totalprice'))*100)
```

Comment: it's calculation something like this (suppose `totalprice` is 500 and `saleprice` is 250, then it's showing output `500-250=250`, but I want to display the output in percentage after calculate, and its output would be `50%` discount. and I will display this discount on the product.

Comment: it's working perfect, but my last query is, how I can display maximum offer product on first priority (Suppose if a product have 90% discount then it should be shown on first and other 80%, 70% discount products should be shown after this)

Comment: @sainitor `.order_by('-offer')`